# Create Output from LOG/TXT file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

This shows the contents of a .log file that logs the use of licenses from a specific vendor. From the log you can for example see that username_1 currently is using license 1, 2, & 3.

```
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_1" username_1@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_2" username_1@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_3" username_1@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_1" username_2@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_2" username_2@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_3" username_2@server459
14:22:49 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_1" username_3@server459
14:46:32 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_2" username_3@server459
14:46:32 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_3" username_3@server459
14:47:40 (VENDOR) OUT: "License_3" username_4@server459
```

I want to create an output that shows how many of each license is in use and exclude all unnecessary data. I envision something like this:

```
License_1: 3
License_2: 3
License_3: 4
```

Comment: So we don't suggest things you know don't work, what have you tried so far? Unless you specify that, your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the license is the only element in double quotes you could use a regex like so:

```
Select-String YourFile.log -Pattern '(?<=")[^"]+(?=")' | % {
  $_.Matches.value
} | Group-Object | % {"$($_.name): $($_.count)"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dave. The license is the only element in double quotes, so that worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool, if my answer worked for you then don't forget to mark it as the excepted answer.

Comment: You should ask another questions not edit your original question otherwise the answers given will not make sense to others when viewing this question..

Answer (score 2):

A variation of [Dave Sexton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34652457/1630171) answer using the `-replace` operator to extract the license substring from the logfile content:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.log') -replace '.*"(license_\d+)".*','$1' |
  Group-Object |
  Select-Object Name, Count
```

That will give you the license count in tabular format. You could pipe it into `Format-Table` to make it more condensed:

```
... | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

If you prefer the custom format from your question you could use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object { '{0}: {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Count }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your log is always looks the same and separated with [Space] then you can use this simple manipulation:

```
$log = Get-Content C:\yourlog.txt
$Array = @()
Foreach ($line in $log)
{
    $Result = "" | Select Time,Vendor,"IN/OUT",License,Username
    $Split = $line -split '\s' | ? {$_}
    $Result.Time = ($Split)[0]
    $Result.Vendor = ($Split)[1]
    $Result."IN/OUT" = ($Split)[2]
    $Result.License = ($Split)[3]
    $Result.Username = ($Split)[4]
    $Array += $Result
}
```

Then you can show all the licenses by specific user:

```
$Array | ? {$_.Username -eq 'username_3@server459'} | Select -Expand License
```